# Flot bar chart - margin for the the largest bar

Tags: margin, flot

Normally, the longest bar spans to the right border. 
I want it like you see on the picture.

[image: two muppets]

I've achieved that by computing the max value and setting xaxis: `{ max: maxValue * 1.1 }`. Again, a bit hacky.

I have tried - without success:

```
            grid: {
                margin: 30,
                minBorderMargin: 10,
            },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the [`autoscaleMargin`](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) property to your `xaxis` options (as long as you aren't setting a min or max value for your `xaxis`):

```
xaxis: {
    autoscaleMargin: .02
}
```

From the [Flot API](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md) documentation:

> The "autoscaleMargin" is a bit esoteric: it's the fraction of margin that the scaling algorithm will add to avoid that the outermost points ends up on the grid border. Note that this margin is only applied when a min or max value is not explicitly set. If a margin is specified, the plot will furthermore extend the axis end-point to the nearest whole tick. The default value is "null" for the x axes and 0.02 for y axes which seems appropriate for most cases.

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/561zaph0/) shows an example of using the `autoscaleMargin` bump the grid border away from the longest bar value.